# Magento - Remove blocks from reference

Tags: php, magento, layout, block

I'm developing an e-commerce website and I'm using Magento CMS.
You can view the site [here](http://maispormenos.eu)

I want the left column to only show the categories list. How can i remove the last block.

PS: This must only happen in the home page

Any further details about layouts are welcome.

Thanks and happy programming

Answer (score 2):

To remove the compare feature from the left sidebar but only on home page:

Go to `/app/design/frontend/default/YOUR_THEME/layout/local.xml`

Find or create the tag `<cms_index_index>` and add the following line:

```
<remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar" />
```

Example:

```
<cms_index_index>
     <remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar" />
</cms_index_index>
```

Comment: thanks, Do you know about a good tutorial, or some reference about layouts for Magento, is something that I'd find very usefull, I googled it but found nothing official and really detailed.

Comment: @MiguelPinto you can get better idea over http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/demystifying-magentos-layout-xml-part-1/